# Replace unicode with HTML tags

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I want to replace the code for IRC bold/colors in Javascript with an HTML tag depending on whether which character it is.

Example bold input:

```
[{{{line}}}] \u0002{{{nick}}}\u0002 was last seen \u0002{{{timeAgo}}}\u0002 whispering     sensually \u0002"{{{message}}}"\u0002
```

Desired output:

```
[{{{line}}}] <span class="bold">{{{nick}}}</span> was last seen <span class="bold">{{{timeAgo}}}</span> saying <span class="bold">"{{{message}}}"</span>
```

Example color input:

```
\u000304error!\u000304
```

Desired output:

```
<span class="color-304">error!</span>
```

Bonus: a way to reverse this operation. This is purely for display purposes, and when I save the template again I want to convert it back to IRC codes.

If there is a library available that meets these requirements, please point me in that direction.

Comment: sounds like a job for an array map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you mean, like this.

```
t = s.replace(/\u0002(.*?)\u0002/g, "<span class=\"bold\">$1</span>");
```

And back again, like this.

```
u = t.replace(/<span class="bold">(.*?)<\/span>/g, "\u0002$1\u0002");
```

You didn't ask this part: The function `document.write` is one way to insert the created HTML into a page. The function `Element.innerHTML` is another.